# 3d Hessian Matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know about Hessian matrices and some of their use cases. (multidimensional Taylor/critical points)

But I wondered if there exists a similar concept of this matrix just in three dimensions (cube) and not just in two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, the "Hessian" is just the collection of second derivatives:
\begin{align}
H_{ij} &= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
\end{align}
Because there are two indices $i$ and $j$, it can be called a "matrix". But there is nothing preventing you from writing down higher derivatives in a similar way. For example you could define
\begin{align}
T_{ijk} &= \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j \partial x_k}
\end{align}
as the "rank 3 tensor" of third derivatives.

The only special thing about the second derivative is the fact that it has a special name, "Hessian (matrix)". Thats just because in many many applications, the second derivative is the highest one used. There is not really anything special about it, mathematically.